# Fitnesse command line fixture

Tags: command-line, fixtures, fitnesse

Does anyone have/"run into" a Fitnesse a Windows commnand line fixutre?  I need to run executables then run my test suites and would appreciate if someone has such a fixture laying around.

Basically, what I am trying to do is the following:

```
|CommandlineFixture|
|C:\dev\myFileImporter.exe -f c:\dev\data\file.txt|
```

Comment: I haven't seen one but it's only a couple of lines of code to write.

Comment: Actually it's easier than I thought - see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Fit, you can try Bob Martin's [CommandLineFixture](http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?CommandLineFixture). You can use it by creating a simple test table as follows:

```
| com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture                |
| command | C:\dev\myFileImporter.exe -f c:\dev\data\file.txt |
```

It also has some nice functionality like being able to search stderr/stdout for certain messages, wait for forked processes to finish, etc.

It's written in Java, and source code is available in case you have to customize it (when I used this, I customized it fairly heavily to add new functionality).

Comment: In case you are looking, the following : |com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture|
|command|env|| produces com.objectmentor.fixtures.CommandLineFixture: Bad table! DecisionTables should have at least three rows.